# Deleting a node from hash table

Tags: c++, hashmap, singly-linked-list

I have created a hash table that contains a singly linked list in each slot of the hash table. I recently changed my code so that when I insert a new node into that hash table, each slot will be a sorted linked list (just insert it into correct spot, rather than sorting it). I currently have this as my delete function:

```
void hashDelete(int key){
    int hashLoc = h(key);
    HashNode *entry = hTable[hashLoc];
    HashNode *prev = NULL;

    if(entry == NULL || entry->value != key){
        cout << "No element found at key" << endl;
       return;
    }

    while(entry->next != NULL){
        prev = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    if(prev != NULL){
        prev->next = entry->next;
    }
    delete entry;
    cout << "Entry Successfully Deleted" << endl;

}
```

This worked for my insert when I would just insert a new node to the end of the linked list but it now doesn't work when I insert a new node to the correct sorted spot of the linked list.

How would I adjust this delete function so that it properly finds and deletes the correct value.

Note: Here is my search function that will search for the value and say whether it is in the hashmap (which works correctly)

```
int hashSearch(int key){
    bool flag = false;
    int hashLoc = h(key);
    HashNode *entry = hTable[hashLoc];
    while(entry != NULL){
        if(entry->value == key){
            return 1;
            flag = true;
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    if(!flag)
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: You have unfortunately built the linked list directly into the hash table. That make is more difficult to isolate the problem.

Comment: When i try to delete a value that is located at the front of the linked list it says it deleted it but it doesn't and when I try to delete a value that is located elsewhere in the linked list it says it is not in the list

Comment: When you delete a node, `entry->next` needs to be stored _somewhere_.  You don't store it anyplace when `prev` is `NULL`.  Where should it be stored?